# Get record from current post

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to get the value of meta_value field from current post.

```
<?php 
    $cupost = $post->ID; 
    $registros = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT meta_value FROM auto_postmeta 
    WHERE post_id = $cupost AND meta_key="mg_game"');
    echo $registros[0]->meta_value . "<br/>";
?>
```

It does not shows the echo from `$registros`.

But if i put directly on the query the number of the post (`post_id = 7`), it shows the value of `meta_value`.

Comment: you have enclosed your query with single quotes, it should be double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thy this out:

```
<?php 
    $cupost = $post->ID;//First check if this variable gets the id, i would echo the $cupost variable to check. 
    $registros = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT meta_value FROM auto_postmeta WHERE post_id = ".$cupost." AND meta_key= 'mg_game' ");
    echo $registros[0]->meta_value . "<br/>";
?>
```

You have to concatenate the Query String with the Php Variables

Comment: Also check out [this](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) doc about prepared statements, it's a more secure way to query to db